# JavaScript prototype array member cannot find push of undefiend

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am trying to implement a stack. when I try to push into the arr this error pops up

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
var MinStack = function() {
    let Min = null;
    const arr = new Array(); // I also tried arr = []
};

/** 
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
    this.arr.push(x);
    this.Min = Math.min(...arr);
};
```

I searched for answers but I didn't find out why can't I access my arr in the constructor?

Comment: you can not because `Min` and `arr` are private properties of the constructor function and can not be accessed by the instantiated ones. Such as when done like `var x = new MinStack()` then `x` has access to it's constructors prototype and known as the `this`, hence `x` is the `this` in `MinStack.prototype.push` but `x` does not have any way to access `Min` or `arr`. So `this.arr` is `undefined`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `this.arr` is not defined.

You have defined the `arr` as a variable as you have used `let` to declare it, but not as a property of the instances of `MinStack`.

Variables declared using `let` or `const` are scoped to the *enclosing block* and not available outside of it.

The `enclosing block` in your case the `function` block, so it becomes a *local variable scoped to the `function`* and not visible outside of it.

When you use a `function` as a constructor and use the `new` keyword to instantiate it a new object is created in memory and is assigned to the `this` reference in the constructor `function`. properties assigned to that `this` reference become properties of the instance created from the constructor `function`:

```js
var MinStack = function() {
    this.Min = null;
    this.arr = new Array(); 
};

/** 
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
    this.arr.push(x);
    this.Min = Math.min(...this.arr);
};

MinStack.prototype.min = function(x) {
    return this.Min;
};

const minArr = new MinStack();
minArr.push(1);
minArr.push(2);
minArr.push(3);
minArr.push(-9);
console.log(minArr.min());
```